# Clearing contents of a cell based on the value of another cell within the same row, based on header references

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to the world of VBA and can't quite wrap my head around this macro  I want to create.

Essentially, I have a monthly data set that comes in, but the data is imperfect. I often need to clear excess data values of one cell, based on the value of another.

The complex part is that  the data will be displaced week to week, and the only thing that is static are the column headers that are included.

Just as an example, columns A thru E have headers Company1, Company2, Company3, etc.
Columns Q thru U have headers Product1, Product2, Product3, etc.

The product columns will contain the company names as values (often more than one, delimited by commas), and if the name of a company doesn't appear for ANY of the product columns, the cell of the same row for that company's column should be cleared.

So if Q4:U4 doesn't contain "*Product1*" as as value, the value at A4 (product 1 column, row 4) should be cleared.

Any insight on how to go about this would be much appreciated!

edit

Screenshot of example data:
[image: Screenshot of example data]

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7yex.png)

Comment: I would loop through the rows of data and for each row loop through the columns you want to check and use `If` statements to check the contents of those cells. Based on your `If` checks, clear the other cells in that row (or don't), then move on to the next row. Shouldn't be too tough.

Comment: What do you want to do with the old and new data? Do you not care about deleting/having a changing structure? You could read in the data in Columns A to E to an array called companies and the data in Columns Q to U to an array called products and then compare them to create a single (or two clean) array to paste back into your original sheet or into another sheet.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of your data set?  just so we can see specifically?

Comment: I've added a screenshot for more clarity. Using the screenshot as the example, columns A through H should only have values if  the rows in columns Q through T contain their respective company as a value in any of the columns. If they're not present in any of the category columns, the value gets removed from that company's row. As an example: Company8 (column H) does not have any values present in line 7, yet still has a value. The value for Company8 at line 7 should be cleared, in this case. The data from columns A to H are copy-pasted into a separate pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Create a new module within the VBA editor and copy in the below code ...

```
Public Sub ProcessData()
    Dim objCompanyRange As Range, objProductRange As Range, objCompanyCell As Range
    Dim strCompany As String, objThisProductRange As Range, rngFrom As Range
    Dim rngTo As Range, objFindResult As Range, lngLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    ' Get the range for the company data.
    Set objCompanyRange = Application.InputBox("Please select the COMPANY data range, including headers ...", "Company Data", , , , , , 8)
    If Err.Description <> "" Then Exit Sub

    ' Get the range for the product data.
    Set objProductRange = Application.InputBox("Please select the PRODUCT data range, including headers ...", "Product Data", , , , , , 8)
    If Err.Description <> "" Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each objCompanyCell In objCompanyRange
        ' We want the headers in the range but want to skip processing the first row.
        If objCompanyCell.Row > objCompanyRange.Cells(1, 1).Row Then
            ' This is the only contentious line for me.  If your headers are specified as you had in your
            ' example, i.e. "Group: Company1" then the below will work.  If that was a mocked example that
            ' was not 100% accurate, the below line will need to change.  It is currently splitting the header
            ' by a colon and only storing the right hand side as the company.
            strCompany = Trim(Split(objCompanyRange.Cells(1, objCompanyCell.Column).Text, ":")(1))

            ' Only reset objThisProductRange if the row has changed, otherwise we use the same set of
            ' products we used last time.
            If objCompanyCell.Row <> lngLastRow Then
                ' Determine the range for the product data given the current row being processed
                With objProductRange.Worksheet
                    Set rngFrom = .Range(.Cells(objCompanyCell.Row, objProductRange.Cells(1, 1).Column).Address)
                    Set rngTo = rngFrom.Offset(0, objProductRange.Columns.Count - 1)
                End With

                Set objThisProductRange = Range(rngFrom.Address & ":" & rngTo.Address)
            End If

            ' Find the company name within the current row of Product data.
            Set objFindResult = objThisProductRange.Find(strCompany, MatchCase:=False)

            ' Clear the cell if nothing was found.
            If objFindResult Is Nothing Then
                objCompanyCell.ClearContents
            End If
        End If

        lngLastRow = objCompanyCell.Row
    Next
End Sub
```

... now watch the animated GIF below to see how you launch it and the resulting output.

[image: Result]

If selecting the datasets each time gives you the sh!ts then feel free to hardcode it or use your own determination method.  It's the easiest approach given I don't know how you may want to do that.

Here's hoping it's what you're after.  Be sure to read the comments in the code in case you have any questions.

Comment: Thinking about it, it may need tweaking if the company names you have cross over, e.g. if you have Company1 and Company10, it will find Company1 within the Company10 name. It may be ok as I have it but something to think about.

Comment: Hey Skin, thanks for looking into this. I ran the macro on the fake data and it worked perfectly, but when I ran it on the live data, it erased all the "Group: Company" data, instead of just those that weren't matched. I tried to reason out why that might be occurring..The live data is really not much different than the fake data I posted, the company headers and category headers all contain colons, the company names in the category columns are delimited by commas in exactly the same way...the only difference really is the company names (and number of companies).

Comment: @dsaurr do you know how to debug in VBA? I’d look at doing that first and foremost. It’s hard for me to work out unless I can use your exact dataset. Is there anyway if sharing the actual workbook?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the live data. I tried a couple things to troubleshoot the issue, and discovered that if I copy-paste the data into a new sheet, then run the macro, it works perfectly. So there's something about how all the columns work together that's breaking the macro. I added a message box to display strCompany and noticed that there were a bunch of headers it was including that it shouldn't have been...I'll try to post another example later today for further clarity.

Comment: Example2 added for  further reference. Using that example I think the Macro is grabbing the "Unrelated" category data, rather than the "Group:" data I specify, unless I copy-paste the data into a separate sheet, and exclude all the unrelated columns.

Comment: @dsaurr So you're saying that the example you provided also doesn't work for you?  I just ran out that example and it worked fine for me so I'm trying to work out where it's all going wrong for you but I'm none the wiser.  I'm really not sure where to go from here.  Do you have special formatting on the headers or data?  Can you get me a screen shot of the debug point where you get weird strHeader data?  That will break it down so I can't see all data.  I may be able to work with that.